# WPF: "{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}" не является допустимым значением для свойства "Foreground"

Tags: wpf

С недавних пор я стал получать ошибку `"{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}" не является допустимым значением для свойства "Foreground".`. Что она означает? Все значения для `Foreground` у меня в проекте либо ссылаются на статический ресурс, либо напрямую прописаны ака `#FFFFFFFF`. Причем в редакторе все работает. Даже `InitializeComponent()` в `MainWindow` успешно выполняется. Эта ошибка появляется после.

---

**UPD**
Судя по всему, проблемма в следующем:
В одном словаре ресурсов лежит стиль для элемента `Label`. Этот стиль ссылается на ресурс `SolidBrush` "`TextColor`", который прописан в другом словаре. При попытке получить его значение стиль получает `UnsetValue`, что и приводит к ошибке.
**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="ModConstructor.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionaries/Basic.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionaries/Palete.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Конфигурации файлов словарей в проекте:
Действие при сборке: Page
Копировать в выходной каталог: Не копировать
Пользовательский инструмент: XamlIntelliSenseFileGenerator

Comment: Если вы не используете Binding, то проблема, с высокой вероятностью в ControlTemplate или DataTemplate. Задайте там значения для Foreground явно и посмотрите, уйдет ли ошибка.

Comment: Это какое то безумие. Я все элементы закомментировал и оставил только пару кнопок и `Label` -- `<Label Content="{Binding title}" Foreground="#FFC8C8C8"/>`. Когда я удаляю этот `Label`, все работает. Однако у меня все еще есть куча элементов, раскомментирование которых продолжает ломать программу.

Comment: 1. У вас точно не применяются шаблоны?
2. Падение происходит только из студии или и при запуске exe тоже приложение падает?

Comment: Так. Тут уже всплывает другая проблема. Смотрите. У меня в словаре `Palette.xaml` прописаны все `SolidBrush` для палитры приложения. В словаре `Basic.xaml` у меня приписан стиль для `Label` (без шаблонов, просто цвет). У меня возникает точно такая же ошибка с кнопкой при наведении курсора, когда она так же должна брать цвет для своего `BorderBrush` из словаря `Palette`. Судя по всему, он не может взять ресурсы из другого словаря.

Comment: По второму пункту. EXE тоже падает.

Comment: Да, тогда надо разбираться с ресурсами, проверьте ссылки как у вас заданы, лучше прописать полные пути, включая сборку.

Comment: Я прописал пути к словарям ака `<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ModConstructor;component/Dictionaries/Basic.xaml"/>`. Ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 3):

Оказалось все достаточно просто. Просто все ссылки из одного словаря на ресурсы другого словаря надо изменить с `StaticResource` на `DynamicResource`.
Спасибо [этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35822760/wpf-merged-resourcedictionary-with-resource-that-binds-to-resource-in-another-di/35824353) на англоязычной версии.